# Set Testid on Native Component

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm integration testing with the tipsi-stripe package using Detox, using the following UI:

[image: Credit Card Sample]

My test is as follows:

```
    ...
    await expect(element(by.text('10'))).toBeVisible()
    await expect(element(by.text('Give $10'))).toBeNotVisible()
    await element(by.text('10')).tap()
    await expect(element(by.text('Give $10'))).toBeVisible()
    await expect(element(by.id('cc-card-input'))).toBeVisible()
    await element(by.id('cc-card-input')).typeText("4242424242424242")
    ...
```

The last line fails with:

```
  ● Signin › allows the person to make a payment

    Error performing 'Click to focus & type text (4242424242424242)' on view '(with tag value: is "cc-card-input" and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE)'.
    > 28 |     await element(by.id('cc-card input')).typeText("4242424242424242")
```

The failure indicates the cc card input isn't able to be typed in.

Heres the component from the library in question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  requireNativeComponent,
  findNodeHandle,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ViewPropTypes,
  Platform,
  Text,
} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import TextInputState from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInputState'

const FieldStylePropType = PropTypes.shape({
  ...ViewPropTypes.style,
  color: PropTypes.string,
})

/**
 * @typedef {Object} PaymentCardTextFieldNativeEventParams
 * @property {string} number -- card number as a string
 * @property {number} expMonth
 * @property {number} expYear
 * @property {string} cvc
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} PaymentCardTextFieldNativeEvent
 * @property {boolean}  valid
 * @property {PaymentCardTextFieldNativeEventParams} params
 */

/**
 * @callback OnChangeCallback
 * @param {PaymentCardTextFieldNativeEvent} params
 */

/**
 * // TODO: Get a more precise type here, not sure how to JSDoc react-native Style Types
 * @typedef {Object} PaymentComponentTextFieldStyleProp
 */

/**
 * A Component that collects the CardNumber, ExpirationDate, and CVC all in one.
 * @typedef {Object} PaymentCardTextFieldProps
 *
 * @property {string} expirationPlaceholder
 * @property {string} numberPlaceholder
 * @property {string} cvcPlaceholder
 * @property {boolean} disabled
 * @property {OnChangeCallback} onChange
 * @property {PaymentComponentTextFieldStyleProp} style
 *
 * @property {string} cursorColor iOS-only!
 * @property {string} textErrorColor iOS-only!
 * @property {string} placeholderColor iOS-only!
 * @property {"default"|"light"|"dark"} keyboardAppearance iOS-only!
 *
 * @property {boolean} setEnabled Android-only!
 * @property {string} backgroundColor Android-only!
 * @property {string} cardNumber Android-only!
 * @property {string} expDate Android-only!
 * @property {string} securityCode Android-only!
 */

const NativePaymentCardTextField = requireNativeComponent('TPSCardField', PaymentCardTextField, {
  nativeOnly: {
    borderColor: true,
    borderWidth: true,
    cornerRadius: true,
    textColor: true,
    fontFamily: true,
    fontWeight: true,
    fontStyle: true,
    fontSize: true,
    enabled: true,
    onChange: true,
    params: true, // Currently iOS only
    keyboardAppearance: true, // iOS only
  },
})

/**
 * @type {import('react').ComponentClass<PaymentCardTextFieldProps>}
 */
export default class PaymentCardTextField extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...ViewPropTypes,
    style: FieldStylePropType,

    // Common
    expirationPlaceholder: PropTypes.string,
    numberPlaceholder: PropTypes.string,
    cvcPlaceholder: PropTypes.string,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,

    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        cursorColor: PropTypes.string,
        textErrorColor: PropTypes.string,
        placeholderColor: PropTypes.string,
        keyboardAppearance: PropTypes.oneOf(['default', 'light', 'dark']),
      },
      android: {
        setEnabled: PropTypes.bool,
        backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
        cardNumber: PropTypes.string,
        expDate: PropTypes.string,
        securityCode: PropTypes.string,
      },
    }),
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    ...View.defaultProps,
  }

  valid = false // eslint-disable-line react/sort-comp
  params = {
    number: '',
    expMonth: 0,
    expYear: 0,
    cvc: '',
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.isFocused()) {
      this.blur()
    }
  }

  isFocused = () => TextInputState.currentlyFocusedField() === findNodeHandle(this.cardTextFieldRef)

  focus = () => {
    TextInputState.focusTextInput(findNodeHandle(this.cardTextFieldRef))
  }

  blur = () => {
    TextInputState.blurTextInput(findNodeHandle(this.cardTextFieldRef))
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    this.focus()
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { onChange, onParamsChange } = this.props
    const { nativeEvent } = event

    this.valid = nativeEvent.valid
    this.params = nativeEvent.params

    if (onChange) {
      // Send the intended parameters back into JS
      onChange({ ...nativeEvent })
    }

    if (onParamsChange) {
      onParamsChange(nativeEvent.valid, nativeEvent.params)
    }
  }

  setCardTextFieldRef = (node) => {
    this.cardTextFieldRef = node
  }

  // Previously on iOS only
  setParams = (params) => {
    this.cardTextFieldRef.setNativeProps({ params })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      style,
      disabled,
      expDate,
      cardNumber,
      securityCode,
      cursorColor,
      textErrorColor,
      placeholderColor,
      numberPlaceholder,
      expirationPlaceholder,
      cvcPlaceholder,
      keyboardAppearance,
      ...rest
    } = this.props

    const {
      borderColor,
      borderWidth,
      borderRadius,
      fontFamily,
      fontWeight,
      fontStyle,
      fontSize,
      overflow,
      backgroundColor,
      color,
      ...fieldStyles
    } = StyleSheet.flatten(style)

    const viewStyles = {
      overflow,
      width: fieldStyles.width,
    }

    const commonStyles = {
      borderColor,
      borderWidth,
      borderRadius,
      backgroundColor,
    }

    return (
      <View style={[commonStyles, viewStyles]}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'red'}}
          rejectResponderTermination
          testID={rest.testID}
          onPress={this.handlePress}
          accessible={rest.accessible}
          accessibilityLabel={rest.accessibilityLabel}
          accessibilityTraits={rest.accessibilityTraits}
        >
          <NativePaymentCardTextField
            ref={this.setCardTextFieldRef}
            style={[styles.field, fieldStyles]}
            borderColor="transparent"
            borderWidth={0}
            cornerRadius={borderRadius}
            textColor={color}
            fontFamily={fontFamily}
            fontWeight={fontWeight}
            fontStyle={fontStyle}
            fontSize={fontSize}
            enabled={!disabled}
            numberPlaceholder={numberPlaceholder}
            expirationPlaceholder={expirationPlaceholder}
            cvcPlaceholder={cvcPlaceholder}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            // iOS only
            cursorColor={cursorColor}
            textErrorColor={textErrorColor}
            placeholderColor={placeholderColor}
            keyboardAppearance={keyboardAppearance}
            // Android only
            cardNumber={cardNumber}
            expDate={expDate}
            securityCode={securityCode}
          />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

You can see that the testID is assigned to the TouchableWithoutFeedBack component - not the component thats being typed in.

I've tried

- setting the testID on the `NativePaymentCardTextField`
- setting `accessible={true}`, with an accessibilityId set on the parent component

[View Hierarchy from Detox](https://gist.github.com/juddey/d7051e382ae000c5a5381c44f5b5a136)

I get the same error on both.

What do I need to do to be able to enter a credit card number into this component (if its even possible)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the hierarchy, it appears that the `cc-card-input` test ID is assigned to a wrapper rather than the text field itself. In particular, this section shows that:

```
    +----------->CreditCardForm{id=243, visibility=VISIBLE, width=787, height=115, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams@ad170a6, tag=cc-card-input, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=3.0, y=3.0, child-count=2} 
    |
    +------------>LinearLayout{id=2131296373, res-name=cc_form_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=703, height=69, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@ce0b53d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=21.0, child-count=2} 
    |
    +------------->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=94, height=53, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@5c61800, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=8.0, child-count=2} 
    |
    +-------------->ImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=84, height=53, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@a86839, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=10.0, y=0.0} 
    |
    +-------------->ImageView{id=-1, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@c8bee7e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
    |
    +------------->CreditCardEntry{id=2131296370, res-name=cc_entry, visibility=VISIBLE, width=609, height=69, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@e74b42c, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=94.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
    |
    +-------------->LinearLayout{id=2131296371, res-name=cc_entry_internal, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1632, height=63, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@1f4748a, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4} 
    |
    +--------------->CreditCardText{id=2131296368, res-name=cc_card, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=63, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@d53dafb, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x2 imeOptions=0x10000006 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=1234 5678 9012 3456 label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null ], x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, hint=1234 5678 9012 3456, input-type=2, ime-target=true, has-links=false} 
    |
    +--------------->TextView{id=2131296374, res-name=cc_four_digits, visibility=VISIBLE, width=104, height=63, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@28ee718, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1080.0, y=0.0, text=4242, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
```

(review the tag associated with the `CreditCardForm` view)

While indeed visible, you can only effectively `typeText()` over views that are text inputs (namely, where a soft keyboard opens).

Repositioning the test ID to the view effectively able to accept input will solve it (it's hard for me to say which exact one that is according to the hierarchy as views seem custom).

Comment: Great answer, but I agree. This question is probably too specific to Detox for Stack Overflow. Should maybe go to Detox themselves?

Comment: Thanks. IMO it's a fair question, bearing the detox tag - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detox